# embedded Java VM for Cortex M3

Tags: jvm, embedded, arm

I'm currently searching for a Java VM which is portable (or already ported) to an ARM Cortex M3 (LPC1768 from NXP, 512kB ROM ). I have already some experience with simple Real Time Java (www.rtjcom.com) which has a small footprint and is well documented. Do you know some more embedded JVMs for Cortex M3? Ideally with a real Byte Code interpreter and a ClassLoader?

Thanks for your suggenstions.

Answer (score 19):

The following a Java VMs target embedded systems:

- [JamaicaVm](http://www.aicas.com/jamaica.html) (Commercial)
- [MicroJVM](http://www.microej.com/pricing/) (Comercial)
- [Aonix Perc](https://www.ptc.com/en/products/developer-tools/perc) (Commercial)
- [PreonVm](http://www.virtenio.com/en/products/virtual-machine.html) (Commercial)
- [AvianVM](https://github.com/ReadyTalk/avian) (Open source)
- [Open Mika](https://github.com/kifferltd/open-mika) (Open source)
- [Squawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squawk_virtual_machine) (Open source)
- [SimplRJT](http://www.rtjcom.com/main.php?p=home) (Open source needs no RTOS for threading support - seems to have disappeared)
- [Kaffe](https://github.com/kaffe/kaffe) (Open source).

This [article by Michael Barr and Jason Steinhorn](http://www.eetindia.co.in/ARTICLES/1998FEB/PDF/EEIOL_1998FEB01_EMS_INTD_TA.pdf) may also be helpful.

Note that on a Cortex M3 it may be very slow.  An ARM part with [Jazelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle) or [ThumbEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Thumb_Execution_Environment_.28ThumbEE.29) may be more appropriate.

Comment: Article link leads to 404

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs : No kidding - it is nearly 7 years old!  It would be impractical to maintain links in old questions and a nonsense to add links to resources that did not exist at the time of asking, especially for a question that would today probably be closed as off-topic being a question that is "_asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_".  When considering the usefulness of a question or answer such as this, one has to consider its age.  I have now voted to close the question, and would consider deleting this answer.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't intentional nitpicking :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at IS2T JVM as well, as the other JVM simply do not run on Cortex M devices.