# Java in Embedded Programming

Tags: java, embedded, microcontroller, firmware

Can java programming be used in micro-controller programming like C and C++? If yes what are the requirement for it? What about in PIC16 and PIC32 series micro controller? Any Possibility for them. I could not find much more information about it in the web too.I appreciate your help. Cheers!!!

Comment: Setting performance aside, with sufficient memory any general purpose processor can run anything which is fully specified, so it really comes down to the question of having sufficient memory onboard or offboard - and if the result would be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run Java on any platform you will need a Java Virtual Machine (JVM).  I would not hold out too much hope for PIC16 due to the memory resources required and perhaps the performance.  If you want the highest performance and smallest footprint then C or C++ are a better (and most usual) solution for embedded systems.

I collated a list of JVMs for embedded systems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856437/embedded-java-vm-for-cortex-m3/10860479#10860479). You will be able to run Java on any target supported by one of those in theory.  Some of the links may be out of date, and you may want to do a search to see if any new tools are available since the list was created.

Many but not all need some sort of kernel scheduler or RTOS to run, so you will need to consider that as well as the target processor.

Answer (score 0):

What microcontroller are you using?

Did you find Javelin? It's possible to program certain microcontrollers with Java.

http://www.parallax.com/tabid/255/Default.aspx

Don't know anything else. Still, I would suggest you to try C. It's fun to try.

EDIT: http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/KVM-J2ME-Java-Virtual-Machine
Bit old link, but maybe it's what you are looking for.