# Dynamic loadable Tasks Embedded Systems

Tags: c, dynamic, embedded, task

How can one make dynamic loadable tasks with an RTOS for an embedded systems.

The dynamics tasks are not created statically but are rather left as relocatables in the final elf image. Then at run time, the code for these tasks is loaded from some memory locations and then run from there.

In short, I dont want static tasks, but rather dynamic tasks in an Embedded System. Can someone guide me how to do that.

EDIT: I would like to know with a bare metal OS like FreeRTOS.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to give more details. Do you mean close to bare-metal with an OS like FreeRTOS or rather a system with a MMU running something like embedded Linux?

Comment: @Étienne. Edited the question acc. to your suggestion. bare-metal FreeRTOS is what I need to know.

Comment: check the ThreadX module loader, it seems similar to your goal: http://rtos.com/products/threadx/downloadable_application_modules

Comment: Related: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919888/running-applications-from-freertos

Comment: @smertrios: Thanks for the link, but my main aim is not only to use but I would like to know how to build such a functionality. How is it done in ThreadX for e.g. The internal working is what I am interested in.